# how to implement realtime america time in android app

Tags: java, android, timezone

i want to implement realtime American clock in android with java.
for this i have tried to use java Date and time API in java but i was unable to do
i don't know how to refresh the time every second in app
i also tried threads but i am confused that how to  do this.

````
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ZonedDateTime obj=ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("-00:00"));

        Set<String> timezones=ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
        timezones.forEach(tz->{
            ZonedDateTime obj=ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(tz));
            System.out.println(tz+" :"+obj.getHour()+":"+obj.getMinute()+":"+obj.getSecond()+" "+obj.getDayOfMonth()+"/"+obj.getMonthValue()+"/"+obj.getYear());
        });

        ZonedDateTime obj=null;
        for (int i = -14; i < 13; i++) 
        {
            if (i>0) {
                obj=ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT+"+i));       
                System.out.println(ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT+"+i) +"     :"+obj.getHour()+":"+obj.getMinute()+":"+obj.getSecond()+" "+obj.getDayOfMonth()+"/"+obj.getMonthValue()+"/"+obj.getYear());
            }else
            {
                obj=ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT"+i));
                System.out.println(ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT"+i) +"     :"+obj.getHour()+":"+obj.getMinute()+":"+obj.getSecond()+" "+obj.getDayOfMonth()+"/"+obj.getMonthValue()+"/"+obj.getYear());
            }
        }

    }
}```
````

Comment: If you are looking for a clock like features , why not use [TextClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock)

Comment: then how to implement different time zones  [like this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.timeanddate.worldclock&referrer=utm_source%3Dtimeanddate%26anid%3Dadmob)

Comment: Using [timezone](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock#attr_android:timeZone) you can set different timezones.